# Why proxy is not used to autowire

Tags: spring, proxy-classes

I can not find any reason why every autowired bean are not autowired by proxy. I know that becasue `@Transactional` annotations do not work and I checked autowired component during debugging in eclipse. Of course every component implements some interface and I use `@Autowired` annotations in relation to the interface. 
I have only one configuration of aop:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I use JPA with hibernate, spring-mvc,spring-webflow, spring-security and spring-data. Interfaces which extends `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` are autowired by proxy. But my components are not. For example I have class `MyClass` which implement `MyInterface`:

```
@Service
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
@Autowired
MyCrudReposiotry reposiotry;
....
}
```

If I autowire MyInterface somewhere:

```
@Autowired
MyInterface mi;
```

then `mi` is just reference to `MyClass` object, repository is refrence to proxy `org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy`. Very interesting is that in testing `mi` is reference to proxy. My test's context does not contain web-flow and mvc configuration.

Maybe there is some indirect aop configuration which I should check. What can switch the autowiring by proxy off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you are scanning for the same components twice. You probably have a  in your root context (for the ContextLoaderListener) and one for the DispatcherServlet. NO if the both scan for the same classes you end up with duplicated (and one proxied and one non proxied instance).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You're right that the problem is `<context:component-scan .. />`. I had `<context:component-scan .. />` only one, but only in DispatcherServlet context. Now I have one `<context:component-scan .. />` for controllers package in `DispatcherServlet` context and second `<context:component-scan .. />` for my services package in root context and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Proxying and auto wiring are independent of each other.  When you use `@AutoWired` it finds another bean that implements the required interface and injects it.  The bean instance it finds might be a normal object or a proxy - it doesn't matter to Autowired.

Proxies are created for certain beans automatically by spring. As you have noticed one scenario in which this happens is when you use `@Transactional`.  When the spring container instantiates a bean which has the `@Transactional` annotation the object gets wrapped in a proxy.  The actual object is replaced by the proxy in the context.  This is done so that spring can intercept calls to those methods and add the begin / commit transaction calls before and after the method call. This is implemented by the spring-aop module.  Any feature that relies on AOP (`@Transactional`, `@Secured`) will result in creation of a proxy.

The other case where proxies are used is to create an implementation on the fly.  In case of the CRUDRepository you are required to only implement the interface.  The implementation of that is created on the fly using the same proxy infrastructure.