# How to autowire class having async methods in another class having async methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-async

I have one class EmailServiceImpl which implements EmailService and another class ReportServiceImpl which implements ReportService. Both the interfaces are annotated with @EnableAsync, and so there are methods with @Async annotations.

I am using default spring taskexecutor.

I am unable to autowire EmailService inside ReportService.

[Please refer to the stacktrace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3UIC.png)

Comment: Stacktrace pls. Async and Autowired shouldn't care about each other. You don't need to enable async support twice but that shouldn't be the issue either.

Comment: I'm not enabling async twice but spring by default creates proxy to async methods and I can't bypass it. Of course Async and Autowired doesn't care about each other, the problem comes when I'm trying to autowire a already proxied class inside another proxy class.

Comment: "Both the interfaces are annotated with @EnableAsync"? Anyway, do you have a stacktrace or error message for the problem? There should be no reason that proxied classes can't be autowired into other proxied classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18995799/995891

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `@EnableAsync`? It says that the annotation needs to be used on a `@Configuration` class, not an interface. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html

Comment: I have added the Stacktrace screenshot

Answer (score 2):

It's working now, I used applicationcontext.getBean("beanName") method to get the bean instead of @Autowired.