# (Transaction not rolling back) Spring-data, JTA, JPA, Wildfly10

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, wildfly, jta

I got this problem for a while and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the context:

- Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE
- Spring-data-jpa 1.10.6.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.5.Final
- I'm using wildfly 10, starting via maven plugin
- configured datasource for JNDI lookup correctly
- using spring-data with @Repository on interfaces
- created entityManagerFactory  as a spring bean (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean)
- as for transaction manager, I tried to use both 'tx:jta-transaction-manager' and spring bean (JtaTransactionManager)
- configured persistence.xml
- enable 'tx:annotation-driven'

So, I got a @Service class (SistemaBOImpl) that has a @Repository injected (SistemaDAO) and a test method for transactional behavior:

```
    @Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class SistemaBOImpl extends AbstractBO<Sistema, Long> implements SistemaBO {

    @Autowired
    public SistemaBOImpl(SistemaDAO sistemaDAO) {
        super(sistemaDAO);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { BusinessException.class })
    public void testTrans() throws BusinessException {
        try {
            final Sistema s = findOne(1L);
            s.setCodUsuAlt(SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(new Date()));
            s.setDatAlt(new Date());
            save(s); //1st save

            save(new Sistema()); //2nd save
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
            // throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SistemaDAO extends DAO<Sistema, Long>, JpaRepository<Sistema, Long> {}
```

**The problem is:**
Although 2nd save won't complete due to database constraints (and I did it on purpose, **1st save is commited and data is changed**.
I can't figure out why it is not rolling back all.
**What am I doing wrong?!?**

Here are my other config file:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans ... ommited namespace hell>
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myco" />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.myco" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Myco_DB" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="tof"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.myco.tof"/>
</bean>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="myco" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Myco_DB</jta-data-source>
    <class>br.com.abril.tof.domain.Sistema</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.1" ...>

<display-name>MyCO</display-name>
<description>MyCO</description>

<!-- Carrega Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myco</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myco</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>jpa/EntityManager</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>myco</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Log/Stacktrace for 2nd save

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not apply work
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWorkInNewTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:112)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:65)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.persist(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
**at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)**
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 65 more
```

Comment: You have `rollbackFor = BusinessException.class` but are throwing a `RuntimeException` in case of an error. The automatic rollback will take place only if the method throws a `BusinessException`, which it does not, so the rollback does not take place (as expected).

Comment: Hi manish, I know that, it was just one of many tests I've made. I tried: ommiting the 'rollbackFor' config and throw both exceptions, I tried putting Runtime and BusinessException on that config and so on...

Comment: Can you debug your application to see if transactions are actually being started for the test? You can put breakpoints in `TransactionInterceptor` to check this. The interceptor intercepts calls to the proxy generated for the Spring managed bean. With your Spring configuration (specifically `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`), the proxy will be an instance of `SistemaBO` (because the default proxies are JDK proxies which proxy interfaces not classes). So, unless `SistemaBO` declares a `testTrans` method with `@Transactional`, there may not be a transaction running when the test runs.

Comment: I updated the question with the stacktrace for the 2nd save and it DOES pass in TransactionInterceptor (I marked between **)

**at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it folks!

After debugging for, like, a lot and searching for flaws on transaction configurations, I ended up seeing that all my Business weren't proxies. Well, that said I thought that it should be spring configuring my beans the issue and, for god sake :), was it.
I got this spring-mvc config done wrong (WEB-INF/myco-servlet.xml):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myco" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

See the **base-package**? It was pointing to the same packages as in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myco" />
```

I just had to change that config in myco-servlet.xml to the main mvc package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myco.service" />
```

And worked just fine!

Kudos for this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995298/why-proxy-is-not-used-to-autowire) also for the enlightment about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MySQL engine you are using is InnoDB. If you are using MyISAM, transaction is not supported.

Comment: Hi Quincy, I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: So is the engine you using supports transaction?

Comment: Well, as I'm using InnoDB... transaction is supported. Also, I assured that MySQL autocommit is set to FALSE.