# Spring Data with JPA not rolling back transaction on error

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have Spring Data configured for JPA. A Service Transaction method doesn't get rolled back for an error (e.g. a DB ConstraintViolationException).

The closest I could find was this
[(Transaction not rolling back) Spring-data, JTA, JPA, Wildfly10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709151/transaction-not-rolling-back-spring-data-jta-jpa-wildfly10)
but we don't have any XML configuration, all of our configuration is Java-based.

Essentially, a service method looks like this: no errors are caught, everything thrown.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
public void insertEvent() throws Exception {
     // Part 1
     EventsT event = new EventsT(); 
     // populate it..
     eventsDAO.save(event);

     // Part 2 - ERROR HAPPENS HERE (Constraint Violation Exception)
     AnswersT answer = new AnswersT();
     // populate it..
     answersDAO.save(answer);   
}
```

Part 2 fails. But after the error and return, I see that the Event (Part 1) is still populated in the DB.

We also tried various combinations of @Transactional, nothing worked:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = ConstraintViolationException.class, readOnly = false)
```

Spring Data CRUD DAO Interfaces:

```
@Repository
public interface EventsDAO extends JpaRepository<EventsT, Integer> {

}

@Repository
public interface AnswersDAO extends JpaRepository<AnswersT, Integer> {

}
```

JpaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myapp.dao")
@PropertySource({ "file:${conf.dir}/myapp/db-connection.properties" })
public class JpaConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.datasource}")
    private String dataSourceName;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", PostgreSQL95Dialect.class.getName());
        //props.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", HashtableCacheProvider.class.getName());
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws NamingException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager( entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.domain", "com.myapp.dao");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(dataSourceName);
    }   

}
```

Have there been any transaction rollback issues with Spring Data & JPA?

Comment: Just for clarification, you are using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` or `javax.transaction.Transactional`? And `insertEvent()` is the first method annotated as `Transactional` in the process?

Comment: The transactional annotation is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. And yes, the insertEvent method is annotated with @Transactional as shown above.

Comment: What are the DB? case MySQL: Rollback isn't possible without engine=InnoDB

Comment: PostgreSQL. In fact, even if I try to do a Delete, Spring Data complains there's no transaction: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query. So a Transaction isn't found, even though I annotated it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not we fixed it. There were 2 parts to the solution:

1) Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to JpaConfig as ledniov described, but that alone wasn't enough;

2) Also in JpaConfig in `entityManagerFactory()`, add the **Service** class package to the following `setPackagesToScan`. Previously, the domain object package was there, but the service object package was not. We added `"myapp.service"`, the 2nd package.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
    lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
    lef.setPackagesToScan("myapp.domain", "myapp.service"); //NOTE: Service was missing
    return lef;
}
```

Comment: This might be a little late but just for share.
I have the same issue and the only reason for my failure is I have to add 
rollBackFor = Exception.class
for @Transactional

I added the package path into the setPackagesToScan and removed it got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation to `JpaConfig` class in order to enable Spring's annotation-driven transaction management capability.

Comment: Good suggestion, I added that, but still the transaction doesn't roll back. I see that Part #1 is retained after the error in Part #2, in the same trans service method.

Comment: We fixed it -- I answered the question. thanks for the help